# Regex para arquivos AFD

Tags: python, regex

Bom dia

Tenho um arquivo Txt com uma série de linhas que dividem as batidas de ponto que temos aqui na empresa.
Cada linha dessas pode conter as informações da batida, como o horário e colaborador.

Porém o meu REP me entrega um arquivo com muitas informações que não são úteis para coleta desses pontos. Sabendo disso pensei em fazer uma verificação REGEX para só pegar o que estiver no padrão estabelecido para as batidas.

(OBS.: O nome do colaborador é opcional. Pode ter ou não.)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual a melhor forma para esse tratamento das informações? Rodar uma verificação de expressão regular a cada interação/linha?

Se sim, como ficaria essa expressão tendo em vista que um AFD segue os padrões abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E você precisa realmente de regex? É só ler o tipo de registro e se for o que você quer é só pegar os outro dados com slices. Ex.: `if linha[9] == '5': data = linha[10:18]` e por aí vai...

Comment: Uma observação, seria legal você [edit] sua pergunta e substituir a imagem com os textos de exemplo por texto de verdade. Assim alguém pode usar pra te ajudar sem precisar digitar todo o texto (spoiler: ninguém faz isso).